# How to convert string date to datetime type in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I am having old database and in those tables every entry maintains `create_at` abd `updated_at` entries,

But this entries are in varchar format e.g: `24/04/2018 14:25:29 pm`

How to I convert this to datetime so I can fire query and get count of records of each month.

Query will be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE MONTH(columnName) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(columnName) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL:**

Use `STR_TO_DATE` function to convert into `datetime`

Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(columnName,'%d%m%Y')) = MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(columnName,'%d%m%Y'))
AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(columnName,'%d%m%Y')) = YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(columnName,'%d%m%Y'))
```

**Demo:**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94c4b/26

**Explanation:**

`STR_TO_DATE`

**Syntax:**  `STR_TO_DATE(str,format)`

It takes a string str and a format string format.
`STR_TO_DATE()` returns a `DATETIME` value if the format string contains both date and time parts, or a DATE or TIME value if the string contains only date or time parts.
If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from str is illegal, `STR_TO_DATE()` returns NULL and produces a warning.

*Specifiers in the format:*

**%d** - Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
**%m** - Month, numeric (00..12)
**%Y** - Year, numeric, four digits
**%T** - Time, 24-hour (hh:mm:ss)

Links To Source:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: @Paritosh Mahale try this solution .

Comment: hey, thank you for response when i am trying `SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(created_at,'%d%m%Y %r')) FROM supplier` it return me `NULL`  for this `24/04/2018 14:25:29 pm` format. I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes you are giving time in 24-hr format with AM and PM which is not valid.

Comment: you can do one thing also remove `%r` since you need `Year` and `Month` Only.

Comment: in my table i am having date format as `17/04/2018`, `24/04/2018 14:25:29` and `23/04/2018 10:50:45 am` but query return null for all

Comment: @ParitoshMahale Try Now I edited my answer. I replaced `%r` with `%T`. Also run the demo link.

Comment: yes, `SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(created_at,'%d%m%Y %T')) FROM supplier` this query return NULL for all records

Comment: Try Again I edited my solution @ParitoshMahale Remove %T and then try and please reply if you tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `substr()` or `substring()` (depending on your database):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE substring(columnName, 4, 2) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND
      substring(columnName, 7, 4) = YEAR(columnName);
```

I would then strongly advise you to change the format of the date/time.  The exact logic depends on the database, but in general, you can do:

```
update table
    set columnName = <convert columnname to date/time>;  -- converts to a date and then back to a string using "default" format

alter table <table> alter columnName datetime;  -- "datetime" is probably the appropriate type, but that depends on the database
```